# How to use channel uri in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification

How many channel should I use to send toast notifications, update of default tile and update of secondary tile?

Just now I use one channel on which i call [BindToShellToast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.bindtoshelltoast(v=vs.105).aspx). I can send toast notifications and tile updates with this channel. Should I use a seperate channel for toast notifications? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed by documentation to use both [BindToShellToast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.bindtoshelltoast(v=vs.105).aspx) and [BindToShellTile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.bindtoshelltile(v=vs.105).aspx) on one channel. As teste you can use a single channel for all push notifications you want to send.

If you dont need to access any resources (e.g. Images) in your push notification [BindToShellToast()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.bindtoshelltoast(v=vs.105).aspx) method to bind your channel. So use it if you need to send toast, tile (text only), raw notifications.

If you also want to use local resources (e.g. Images) e.g. for updating the background of a tile use the [BindToShellTile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.bindtoshelltile(v=vs.105).aspx) method to bind your channel.

If you also want to use non local resources (e.g. web images) e.g. for updating the background of a tile use the [BindToShellTile(Collection)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff708021(v=vs.105).aspx) method to bind your channel.